# spring JPA query with spel expression for random

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql, spring-el

I am trying to generate a random number so I can do sampling in a data set in a JPA query. I have read this is totally possible everywhere but I keep getting errors:

code:

```
@Query("select t from Telemetry t where t.id = :id and t.updateTimestamp between :startTime and :endTime and #{ #T(java.lang.Math).random() } < :samplingRate ")
Iterable<Telemetry> findFor(@Param("id") String org, @Param("startTime") Instant startTime, @Param("endTime") Instant endTime, @Param("samplingRate") Float samplingRate);
```

error:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '#' [select t from
>   com.mz.rad.dao.Telemetry t where t.id = :id and t.updateTimestamp
>   between :startTime and :endTime and #{ #T(java.lang.Math).random() } <
>   :samplingRate ]

Digging deeper into this I discover this exception:

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter with that position [" + parameterPosition + "] did not exist");
```

parameter position is 1 or 2 Depending on which syntax I use.

I have tried with with/without hashes. No luck. I am using postgres which has a `random()` function but it doesn't like me invoking that either (which is my ultimate goal).

This question is about using SPeL, but I just need a random number

Answer (score 4):

You can try like this `:#`

```
select t from Telemetry t where t.id = :id and t.updateTimestamp between :startTime and :endTime and :#{T(java.lang.Math).random()} < :samplingRate
```

If not then use `?#`

```
select t from Telemetry t where t.id = :id and t.updateTimestamp between :startTime and :endTime and ?#{T(java.lang.Math).random()} < :samplingRate
```

Comment: I gave you an upvote but found my own answer. Need to pom bump too

Answer (score 1):

[Answer](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions):

```
@Query("select t from Telemetry t where t.id = :id and t.updateTimestamp between :startTime and :endTime and :#{T(java.lang.Math).random()} < :samplingRate ")
```

Helps to bump your POM

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Yeah, I got it working .. now it randomly returns ALL or NO result `samplingFactor` times :-/ new question